# Mobile deeplink in gmail app to specific profile

Tags: react-native, mobile, gmail

Is it possible to open the gmail app through deeplink and also set the current google account.

Something like `googlegmail://email` ?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve. Do you want to open your app after opening a link or do you want your app to open a email client?

Comment: I want to open the gmail app, but the inbox of a specific account. If it's possible ofc

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible at android but in iOS there no apis available to choose an account for the mail client. You can open your app with deep linking https://medium.com/wolox/ios-deep-linking-url-scheme-vs-universal-links-50abd3802f97 or you can open the link with linking https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking.html